# Reset daterangepicker.js date value on cancel

Tags: jquery

I'm using the [Date Range Picker by Dangrossman](https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker) and what I essentially need to do is to clear the date when I click on the cancel button.

From what I have read there is no way in the script to call this action but I have read that I could essentially destroy and recreate the date range picker however I'm having a hard time implementing the code.

Here is what I have so far. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(function() {      
    $('.tqm-events-filter__button--date').daterangepicker({
        alwaysToggle: true,
        parentEl: "#tqm-date-range-picker__container",
        locale: { 
            cancelLabel: 'Clear filters',
            applyLabel: 'Apply filters'
        }
    });

    $('.tqm-events-filter__button--date').click(function() {
        $('.tqm-events-filter__button--checklist-item').each(function() {
            $(this).next().hide();
        });
        $('#tqm-date-range-picker__container').show();
    });
});

$('.tqm-events-filter__button--date').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function() {
    $('.tqm-events-filter__button--date').removeClass('tqm-apply-event-filter-button');
    $('#tqm-date-range-picker__container').hide();
    $('.tqm-events-filter__button--date').daterangepicker('destroy');
    $('.tqm-events-filter__button--date').daterangepicker({
        alwaysToggle: true,
        parentEl: "#tqm-date-range-picker__container",
        locale: { 
            cancelLabel: 'Clear filters',
            applyLabel: 'Apply filters'
        }
    });       
});
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: I never saw anything about daterangepicker('destroy') in the linked documentation. To me it seems it just re-initializes the daterangepicker with some default options. So when you call daterangepicker('destroy') and then daterangepicker({...}); you probably just reinitialize it twice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [jQuery's .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to set an input value.

So in your case, when the cancel function is triggered, you can use jQuery's .val() method to set the targeted input's value to an empty string.

This can be further seen in action on the [Date range picker website](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#example5) (line 17)

```
$('.tqm-events-filter__button--date').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(.targeted-input).val('');
  });
```

Comment: this will clear only input only. not datepicker selected values

Answer (score 0):

Based on Amiracle suggestion this was my final working solution. I assigned new dates to the daterangepicker.

```
    $('.tqm-events-filter__button--date').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function() {
        $('.tqm-events-filter__button--date').removeClass('tqm-apply-event-filter-button');
        $('#tqm-date-range-picker__container').hide();
        $('.tqm-events-filter__button--date').data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(new Date);
        $('.tqm-events-filter__button--date').data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(new Date);
    });
```

Comment: Much better solution

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('.tqm-events-filter__button--date').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker)
{
    $(this).data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(moment().format("MM-DD-YYYY")); //date now
    $(this).data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(moment().format("MM-DD-YYYY"));//date now
});
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on SO, please add some explanations to your answer.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.